# Getting "Could not locate PropertySource: Error requesting access token" error in PCF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, cloud-foundry

An app is failing with the following error:

```sh
00:27:36.300 WARN [my-sample-api,,,] 19 --- [ main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: Error requesting access token.
```

I have tried the following with no success:

1. Re-bound the `config-server` service to the app.
2. Re-created the `config-server` and bound it to the app.
3. Updated the `config-server` with another property source url.

My application works on a different environment that uses the same property source and application build.

Any clues how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post more logs? Also, try setting the log level for `org.springframework.cloud` and `io.pivotal` to DEBUG, and retrying. Then post a much larger snippet of logs. Also, double check your SCS client libraries and make sure you have a version that matches the version of your config server.

Comment: There weren't any other logs related to this even with DEBUG on. However I realized I had proxy configured in the `manifest.yml` and removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues couldn't be found in the logs so I decided to look elsewhere when I saw there was a proxy set in the `JAVA_OPTS` in the `manifest.yml`. So if someone runs into this issue, check your deployment pipeline and make sure you do not have proxy set, or if you do make sure it can reach PCF.